# Actor not response

Tags: scala, actor, scala-2.9

Take a look at the code snippet:

```
import scala.actors.Actor._

object ActorTest1 extends Application {
  val caller = self

  val badActor = actor {
     receive {
        case msg =>
          println(Thread.currentThread()+ " "+msg)
          caller ! "bbbb"
     }
  }

  badActor ! "aaaa"
  receive {
     case a: String => println(Thread.currentThread() + " " + a)
  }
```

}

After badActor resonse "bbbb" to the sender, the whole application block . but if I change `caller ! "bbbb"` to `sender ! "bbbb"`, it will work.

Could anyone explain why ?

Comment: Works for me with `App` instead of deprecated `Application`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that your caller reference is actually a reference to self, which is not an actor instance! :-)

instead sender is a a valid instance, as you can see here:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

Comment: starting from scala 2.10 the actor system is deprecated, and replaced with akka:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html